# How can you find a backgound image y-offset using javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, background, offset

Pretty straight forward I suppose. Getting the background position is easy, but just getting the Y position seems to be a bit tougher. Do I have to splice up the background position output? Or is there a cleaner way of getting the value?

EDIT: I was able to get this, the javascript version of Damien-at-SF's answer, but for some reason yResult returns '(an empty string)' when I do a console.log() for it.I don't think it's actually grabbing the value. What am I doing wrong?

```
var yResult = document.getElementById('sub-image1').style.backgroundPosition;
var a = yResult.split(" ");
var y = parseFloat(a[1]);
```

Comment: What element is the image applied to?

Comment: the issue is the standard javascript method (that you used above) doesnt read stylesheets, only inline css... check my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery for wide browser support:

```
//returns y position of background image
$("#example").css("background-position").split(' ')[1]
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/QagqS/

That example alerts the y position of the background image :)

**UPDATE WITHOUT JQUERY:**

For standard javascript ( http://jsfiddle.net/QagqS/3/ ), you need to define your css inline, within the element:

```
<div id="example" style="background-position:10px 100px"></div>
```

This allows the javascript to pick up on the style of the element and as such you can use the

```
document.getElementById('example').style.backgroundPosition.split(' ')[1]
```

method posted above...

Comment: It would need to be just javascript.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see. Writing it inline feels like it would do the trick. I'll have to test later at home

Comment: :) you can see it working in the second example link http://jsfiddle.net/QagqS/3/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<element>.style.backgroundPositionY`, but i am unsure how widely supported it is.